# clearing a list of domains / remove subdomains

Tags: csv, notepad++, bulk

I have a large list of domains which is mixed with subdomains.

```
google.de
spiegel.de
sub1.google.de
zeit.de
sub1.spiegel.de
```

Is there a tool or a workaround in an editor (e.g. Sublime or Notepad++) to get all before domain.tld deleted?

Notepad++ helped me to get this list cleared from all the other content, which has been inside. But at this point a stopped.

Comment: Do you also have domains that use more than three levels (e.g. `.co.uk` domains) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean removing the ***.something.something, search for regular expression

```
^.*\..*\..*
```

and replace with nothing.

EDIT: version 2, where you want to keep part of the line (a duplicate in your example):

```
^.*\.(.*\..*)
```

replaced with

```
$1
```

The () and . take their regular expression meaning (grouping and any character), and the \. escapes the . to find that character. $1 gets what's inside the (first) set of () if the search expression (as $2 would get the second part if present...)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now I get the hole line with a subdomain found.
How can I get the sub-part of the domain replaced with nothing?
sub.google.de -> google.de

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:.+\.)?([^.\r\n]+\.[^.\r\n]+)$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # beginning of line
  (?:               # start non capture group
    .+              # 1 or more any character but newline
    \.              # a dot
  )?                # end group, optional
  (                 # start group 1
    [^.\r\n]+       # 1 or more non dot, non linebreak
    \.              # a dot
    [^.\r\n]+       # 1 or more non dot, non linebreak
  )                 # end group
$                   # end of line
```

**Result for given example:**

```
google.de
spiegel.de
google.de
zeit.de
spiegel.de
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have `awk` command line tool.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="."} NF==3{$0=substr($0, length($1)+2)}1' input.txt
```

Input file `input.txt`:

```
google.de
spiegel.de
sub1.google.de
zeit.de
sub1.spiegel.de
```

Output:

```
google.de
spiegel.de
google.de
zeit.de
spiegel.de
```

Hope thats what you wanted.

Script explanation:

```
BEGIN{FS="."}    # set input line field separator to  .
NF==3{$0 = substr($0, length($1)+2)} # if input line has 3 fields, Remove the first field
1                # output modified line
```

For the more general case when there are more that 3 domain qualifiers.

```
BEGIN{FS=OFS="."}    # set input line field separator to  .
NF > 2{                # if there are more than 2 input fields
        while(NF > 2) $0 =substr($0, length($1)+2); #remove the first field from input line
    }              
1                # output modified line
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But when I input: google.de
spiegel.de
sub1.google.de
zeit.de
sub1.spiegel.de

I want to get google.de
spiegel.de
google.de
zeit.de
spiegel.de.

I want to get the subs removed.

Comment: fixed to @deelite request.